# File Handling in C

Tags: c, file-io

Sorry for asking very simple question.I'm new to coding.
Input `txt` file

`5,3

001

110

111

110

001`

I need to print the output as

U1: 001
U2: 110
U3: 111
U4: 110
U5: 001

Upto now I was able to print the contents with this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  void main() {
    FILE *fopen(), *fp;
    int c;

    fp = fopen("read.txt","r");
    c = getc(fp) ;

    while (c!= EOF) {
      putchar(c);
      c = getc(fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
  }
```

Can Anybody tell how should I proceed?

Comment: I'm reading but can u show some direction.

Comment: One tip: use more than 1 space for indentation. It's rather hard to read your code.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590, Kernighan and Ritchie, for instance. You really sound like you need to make some effort of your own here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your work is done inside the `while` loop.
But you're not doing enough work ...
a) you need to count lines
b) you need to print the `"U#"`

Suggestion: create a variable for the line counting business and rewrite your loop to consider it. Here's a few snippets

```
int linecount = 0;
```

```
printf("U%d: ", linecount)
```

```
if (c == '\n') linecount += 1;
```

---

Oh! You really shouldn't add the prototype for `fopen` yourself. It is already specified with `#include <stdio.h>`.

And **well done for declaring `c` as `int`**. *Many people do the error of declaring it `char` which is incompatible with `EOF` and all the range of characters*

Answer (score 0):

I would read the data a line at a time with `fgets`. When you have a complete line in a buffer, it'll be pretty easy to get `fprintf` to put in your line header with a format like "U%d: %s\n".